# Data migration to Heroku Postgres DB?

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

What options do I have to migrate data to hosted with Heroku Postgres Database?

I have Django app  and my client  is migrating is moving from his  existing software will most likely produce data in excel format. I will figure out the data model and data conversion  I just need to know what tools to use to do the actual update of the DB.

Comment: You could manually convert the excel file to fixtures. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/initial-data/. This is what I did with my last client. Except I had access to the database and dumped the data into a json file which made it easier to create into fixtures.

Answer (score 1):

Your Question is probably too broad for this site. But briefly, for Postgres in general…

## `INSERT`

The usual way to put data into a SQL database is the [`INSERT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html) command.

## `COPY FROM`

To add data in bulk rather than one record at a time, call [`COPY FROM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html). You specify a file to be imported.